# ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output - no access to FTP

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, login, cookies, ftp

I updated some plug-ins for our client on Friday, since then I've been unable to load the admmin log-in page http://idealts.co.uk/wp-admin/ and when I try the log-in page it won't allow me to log-in http://idealts.co.uk/wp-login.php , I get the message: ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output.

I don't have access to the FTP site which was used to set up the website. Any suggestions on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated in `wp-login.php` , it happens if server is unable to set cookies, this can happen due to several reasons, one of the common issue is: output being sent before setting up of cookies.

Try out following options:

1. Update WordPress core, if it is not up to date
2. change theme, if you are using custom theme
3. If issue still persists, rename plugin folder
4. Also check error log, errors may not be printed to screen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but how do I access the settings when I cannot log-in?

Comment: Oh, you can do these if you have FTP, so without FTP and without wp-admin login you can't fix the problem anyway. Also I would suggest to try to contact with your hosting support, because this might have been the server side problem

Comment: Great, thats useful, I'll follow that line of enquiry.

Comment: If you think my answer is useful, than please vote up :)

Comment: Done, have added tick, but as a newbie isn't visible

Comment: I still can't access the hosting for the site, so still unable to access the back-end of the website. All I did on Friday was update some plug-ins. Grr!